# parallel programming in r using doParallel and foreach

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing

I get the correct output when I use %do% (sequential processing) in foreach

However, the the script gets stuck when I try %dopar% (parallel processing) in foreach

```
for(i in seq(10,8,-2)){

   for(j in seq(10,8,-2)){

     foreach(k = 96:100,.packages=c('recommenderlab','ggplot2','reshape2') ) %dopar% {  

      results <- run_algorithms(r.binary, "cross", k, k)

      #plot the performance of the three algos
      jpeg(sprintf('u_%d_d_%d_%d.jpg',i,j,k))
      plot(results,annotate=c(1,3),legend="topleft")  

      dev.off()  
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually indicative of an improperly configured parallel backend. How did you set up your parallel backend? Show output of `sessionInfo()` and include code used to set up the backend.

Comment: I was using this: registerDoParallel(detectCores())      now i am using this: cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)

Comment: Please provide `sessionInfo()` -- depending on the type of system you are on, many things could be going wrong including file permissions to install and load packages in the slave processes and writing to disk.

Comment: We will need the  entire code and data to reproduce this. Please provide us with a reproducible example ([here are some suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions, the problem solved when i assigned the foreach to a variable like in the examples in official documentation:  result <- foreach(k = 96:100,.packages=c('recommenderlab','ggplot2','reshape2')) %dopar% {  ...}
I will provide a reproducible  example also.